# IntelliJ Idea 13 setup Scala / Windows 7

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I can't seem to get Idea to work with Scala properly...

After some Googleing around I got it to create a project structure, but a simple Hello World doesn't seem to get going.

So far I have downloaded the Scala plugin, the Scala repl and JDK 8.

[image: scala]
[image: java]

[image: A picture speaks louder than words:]
[image: external libs]

(side-question: Is there a reason why Idea doesn't play well with Scala out of the box?)

**UPDATE:**
after doing what was suggested below: I get the following

(adding the scala libs did get me a bit closer)
[image: this]
[image: and this]

Comment: Please change sreenshot with expanded `External Libraries`.

Comment: Did you install Scala on you machine ? Open terminal and run `scala -version` what it say ?

Comment: added screenshots again

Answer (score 1):

## IntelliJ 14: [Scala SDK library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27300750/2650174)

## IntelliJ 13:

In IntelliJ you need add Scala libraries as `Global Libraries`. Open **Project Structure** [image] and define Scala. Provide path to `SCALA_HOME`; on Windows home dir should be `C:\Program Files\Scala`:

[image]

Then add Scala [Facet](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/facet.html) define Scala Compiler:

[image]

Apply new configurations. Your issue should resolved!

---

Useful resources:

- [**IntelliJ & Scala Development**](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Scala+Development)
- [**IntelliJ & Scala screencasts**](https://www.youtube.com/user/intellijideavideo/search?query=scala)

Comment: thanks, that got me a bit further, I updated my question with the current status.