# Why does IDEA 14 report "Cannot load facet "Scala": Unknown type of facet "scala""?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run play framework application in Intellij IDEA 14.

I installed the Scala plugin and have all jar files required.

However inside the `Project-Structure -> Facet`, I cannot find the Scala facet in the adding list. And also it errors with:

> Cannot load facet "Scala": Unknown type of facet "scala"

I tried to create a new project with SBT, still I cannot find the Scala facet in the adding list. Although I could compile Scala source files.

Is there anything wrong with the Scala plugin? Or I didn't get configuration for IntelliJ IDEA 14 right?

Comment: Yeap, you're correct, uninstalling SBT plugin didn't helped, it appeared as "fixed" for me for a while.. probably Idea didn't reported the problem unless it re-indexed the project, then it failed again. Sorry for wrong answer (deleted it) and thanks for the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Scala SDK library

In new IntelliJ 14.1+ the Scala facet have replaced as *Scala SDK* library that, in addition to the standard Scala libraries, has a classpath to Scala compiler:

[image]

For more updates follow as per **[IntellJ's blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/10/30/scala-plugin-update-for-intellij-idea-14-rc-is-out/)**.